# "Your account is still active" (FireDigit Hotspot Manager)

Tags: wireless-networking, hotspot

My employer uses FireDigit Hotspot Manager to manage our wireless network. Of late, some users have complained that they keep getting the message "Your account is still active" when logging into the hotspot, with correct credentials. When they get this message, they are unable to use our internet connection.

We have tried logging them out of their session, which did not help. We have deleted and remade their accounts, which did help. When we try to logout the session, we get an error saying: "Error 202 => Unknown user MAC address".

Any ideas?

Comment: What did FireDigit's support say?

Comment: They told me to buy a support agreement if I wanted support. It's a pretty old setup, from long before I started in the firm.